# Force Tomcat to redirect to HTTPS without changing web.xml security constraints

Tags: tomcat, ssl, web.xml

I already know how to configure Tomcat so that it redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS:

1. enable and configure the SSL connector
2. set correct "redirectPort" attribute on the non-SSL connector
3. modify web.xml and set the "transport-guarantee" to "CONFIDENTIAL"

My question is:
Is there a way to achieve the same result **WITHOUT modifying the web.xml file**?

I'm looking for a solution where I do not have to change the web application, which is deployed as WAR file. So changes like adding a servlet filter or implementing the redirect inside the web application are not an option.

Thanks for any help!

Stephan

Comment: Do you want all the apps on that Tomcat to only use HTTPS? If so, are you able to change the server.xml or is that not possible?

Comment: @Darius X: In my special case, I don't care because I know that there will be only one webapp. But having a solution where it can be enabled on a per-webapp or per-host base would maybe help other people.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to modify the application WAR file, you can also add this entry to the server WEB.XML (`/tomcat/conf/web.xml`) and limit which webapps this parameter applies to?

Answer (score 2):

Consider implementing a custom Tomcat [Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html) for doing the redirect. [ValveBase](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ValveBase.html) is a good start.

Comment: I had a very similar idea. I've implemented a custom [Realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Realm.html) extending [CombinedRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/CombinedRealm.html). That allows me wrap my realm around an existing realm. By overriding the method "findSecurityConstraints", I can "patch" the transport guarantee setting at runtime. It already works pretty good and I will post my solution as soon as it is production ready.